# Updating and saving canvas upon form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have the following code, which executes before a form is submitted.

I'm changing an image then redrawing a canvas before saving that image.

the problem I have is that it doesn't work as intended (instead it saves the image with the previous image src attribute)...

If I step through it in firebug the correct image is saved, which leads me to think there needs to be a delay before it saves....

How do I do it?

```
$('#WindowForm').submit(function () {
            if (isInternal)
            {
                imgsrc = $(".externalColor.selected-color").find('img').attr("src");
                draw();

                var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

                context.drawImage(can, 0, 0)

                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
                $("#ImageData").val(dataURL);
                return true;
            }

        });
```

Note that there is an onload in the draw method too:

```
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = imgsrc;    
 img.onload = function () {
                    pattern = context.createPattern(img, "repeat");
                    context.fillStyle = pattern;
                    DrawContext(context);


                };
```

Comment: I'm confused by your code, perhaps you can clear a few things up for me. What is the variable `can` pointing to? Should `imgsrc` actually be `img.src`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very likely that you need to wait for the image to load in your `draw()` function. The best way would be to include a callback parameter in your function, so you could save after it is finished.

```
function draw(callback){
    //...
    img.onload = (function(callback){
        return function(){
            //...create your pattern...
            callback.call();
        };
    })(callback);
}

draw(function(){ /* ...save image... */ });
```

You could also use something like `setTimeout(function(){ /*...save image...*/ }, 1);` but this isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it like this:

```
$( 'form' ).on(
    'submit',
    function( evt ) {

        var form = $( this );

        evt.preventDefault(); // prevent the form submission

        // ...do stuff...

        // delay the submission
        window.setTimeout(
            function() {

                form.off( 'submit' ); // remove this event handler
                form.submit(); // manually submit the form

            },
            500 // or whatever
        );

    }
);
```

This basically stops the form from being submitted until everything is sorted, then manually submits it. You might want to combine this with @Evilzebra's answer and stick the timeout function in an onload event for the created image, however the basic principles will be the same (prevent submission, then manually submit once ready).

**N.B.** you need to unbind the event handler before the manual submit, or the submit event will fire again and just keep running in a loop!

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code I think I understand what you're trying to do, and why its not working. First off I think your example code has some errors that shouldn't be there. I'm going to assume that `imgsrc` should be `img.src` at which point your making an asynchronous call to load a new image, which most likely won't be done until after you've competed the rest of this function. A quick and easy way to remedy this is to create a flag that lets the `img.onload` know if it should be saving the image or not. In the below example I key off of `isInternal`

```
$('#WindowForm').submit(function (e) {
    if (isInternal)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        imgsrc = $(".externalColor.selected-color").find('img').attr("src");
        // this will then cause the img.onload to fire
    };
});

function pleaseSubmitMe(){
    draw();
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    context.drawImage(can, 0, 0)
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    $("#ImageData").val(dataURL);
    // alright now that thats done, lets submit this bad boy
    isInternal= false; // we need to set this to false so we actually try submitting
    $('#WindowForm').submit();
}

img.onload = function () {
    pattern = context.createPattern(img, "repeat");
    context.fillStyle = pattern;
    DrawContext(context);
    // if I'm Internal lets send this image to be submitted
    if(isInternal){
        pleaseSubmitMe();
    }
};
```